# Is there a way if I do git checkout a file of older version and then later git pull to get latest file again

Tags: php, git, version, git-pull, vcs-checkout

I have a file which I had checkout out using previous git hash code 
using command :
        `git checkout 1a4f8901b3b3b52903ac7c8e7aa7a0a7ba95b4f1 -- example/abcxyz.php`

now whenever I update any file and do git pull, `git pull` the 
command is unable to pull the above checkout file.

so if anyone can help me to get the latest commit of that file . And why it is not checkout that file?

Comment: Please edit your question properly.

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is that you want to do with the checked out file. But here are possible solutions:

- If you want to stash the checked out file

  ```
  git stash
  git pull
  ```
- If you want to remove the changes done to the file

  ```
  git checkout .
  git pull
  ```
- If you want to stage and commit the file

  ```
  git add example/abcxyz.php
  git commit -m "commit message"
  git pull
  ```

Let me know if any of these help you with your issue.

Comment: i have checkout previous version by above given command., but i think by default when i do git pull it should override that ```abcxyz.php``` file . but it is not happening ,why?

Comment: when running `git pull` it merges the changes from the remote. However when you've unstaged changes in your repository, it is impossible for `git` to merge the changes in the files. This is the expected behaviour. I'd recommend that you take a look at [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) for more information.

Comment: thanks ,... i can get the problem solved by again doing git checkout filename without specify version.
like ```git chekout example/abcxyz.php```

Comment: Cool. That is similar to the second scenario in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` does not do what you think it does.

In particular, `git pull` does not "pull files" at all!

What `git pull` does is:

1. run `git fetch`;
2. run a second Git command, usually `git merge`.

The first command—the `git fetch` part of `git pull`—has your Git call up some other Git, usually the Git at the URL you have stored under the name `origin`.  This other Git may have some commits that you do not have yet.  If so, the other Git gives those commits to your Git, along with the branch names that the other Git uses to *remember* those commits.  Your Git then *renames* their branches, so that your Git remembers their `master` under your name `origin/master`, their `dev` under `origin/dev`, and so on.

Having learned of any new commits they have that you don't, it's now possible for your Git to run `git merge` on one of those commit hash IDs.  If you have not told it otherwise, your `git pull` command does that now.

A merge operation merges "what you did"—which in this case, includes "set this file back in time"—with "what they did".  To do this, the merge must first find a commit that you share with them.  If you're on your `master` branch, for instance, you might find the last commit you have that is also on your `origin/master` (this being your Git's way of remembering their `master`).  Your Git can then compare:

- What was in this old commit, and what's in your current commit?  Whatever is different, you must have changed.
- What was in this old commit, and what's in *their* current commit?  Whatever is different, *they* must have changed.

If they did *not* change the file, and you *did* change the file—you did change the file, you said so yourself—then Git will *keep your changes*.

(Note that if you have not *committed* your changes, doing this kind of `git merge` is tricky and not a good idea.  If you don't *want* your changes, you can discard them using `git reset` or `git checkout`; any reasonably modern Git will give you advice on this with `git status`.  If you *do* want to keep your changes, you should commit them.)